# use live555 to stream H264 to VLC

Tags: h.264, vlc, live-streaming, live555

I try to stream H264 to VLC via RTP without RTSP, that is to receive H.264 stream from IP camera, and send it to VLC on anther host. VLC opened URL “**rtp://@:12345**”.
  Notice that openRTSP doing the same thing but output data into file using H264VideoFileSink class, I replace that part of code:

```
 if (strcmp(subsession->mediumName(), "video") == 0) {
    if (strcmp(subsession->codecName(), "H264") == 0) {
      // For H.264 video stream, we use a special sink that adds 'start codes',
      // and (at the start) the SPS and PPS NAL units:
      //fileSink = H264VideoFileSink::createNew(*env, outFileName,
            //            subsession->fmtp_spropparametersets(),
            //            fileSinkBufferSize, oneFilePerFrame);

      char const* outputAddressStr = "192.168.1.123"; // this could also be unicast
      struct in_addr outputAddress;
      outputAddress.s_addr = our_inet_addr(outputAddressStr);

      const Port outputPort(12345);
      unsigned char const outputTTL = 255;

      Groupsock outputGroupsock(*env, outputAddress, outputPort, outputTTL);
      rtpSink = H264VideoRTPSink::createNew(*env, &outputGroupsock, 96);
   }
…
```

then,

```
    subsession->sink = rtpSink;
    subsession->sink->startPlaying(*(subsession->readSource()),
        subsessionAfterPlaying,
        subsession);
```

The result is that openRTSP is running but VLC received nothing. I used Wireshark to check, no packet sent to destination IP and port.

I also try testMP3Streamer, replace multicast address with the unicast address aboved. VLC could play it.
  Could anybody give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is severals errors in your code, first the `Groupsock` scope is too narrow, next an H264 Framer is needed to feed an `H264VideoRTPSink`, as you can see in H264VideoRTPSink.cpp :

```
Boolean H264VideoRTPSink::sourceIsCompatibleWithUs(MediaSource& source) {
  // Our source must be an appropriate framer:
  return source.isH264VideoStreamFramer();
}
```

Then putting all together will give something like :

```
char const* outputAddressStr = "192.168.1.123"; 
struct in_addr outputAddress;
outputAddress.s_addr = our_inet_addr(outputAddressStr);

const Port outputPort(12345);
unsigned char const outputTTL = 255;

Groupsock* outputGroupsock = new Groupsock(*env, outputAddress, outputPort, outputTTL);
rtpSink = H264VideoRTPSink::createNew(*env, outputGroupsock, 96);

subsession->addFilter(H264VideoStreamDiscreteFramer::createNew(*env, subsession->readSource()));
```

Comment: It works！VLC says “A description in SDP format is required to receive the RTP stream. Note that rtp:// URIs cannot work with dynamic RTP payload format (96).” It means VLC received RTP packets actually. Thank you.

Comment: The above solution for streaming h264.  Is any sample available for playing H264 using H264VideoRTPSink instead of DummySink provided in RTSP sample by live555